# How to draw a colored line in dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

I am facing trouble drawing a colored line in the console using dev C++.

I have tried searching it in Google but cant find a single code related to it.

Comment: If applicable, please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.6.1 or 4.7.0, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/.

Answer (score 0):

You need a graphics library. In TC, you can use graphics.h, but graphics.h can't be used in dev c++ because of incompatible compiler. But you can choose openGL or just windows API.

Comment: Yes, the Windows API would be fine. The Forger wrote a nice tutorial about using GDI to draw graphics: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: can you send me the code because i havent used openGL before and have no idea of its syntax